# How to handle offsite payment in mobile app powered by Laravel api

Tags: laravel, flutter, payment

I have Laravel application with offsite payment *(payments are handled by the third party then redirected to my application with payment id)*.

In the same I'm working with Flutter developer to integrate the same payment method/gateway into the mobile app, and I was wondering how can we pull the same behavior on the mobile app?

**My attempt**

1. send payment url to mobile app with api flag on it.
2. Mobile app will open secure web view to the user to pay.
3. after payment is done redirect user back to success/failure page and create invoice.
4. mobile app will be asking endpoint every 2 seconds if the initial payment was success.

I know this is a very bad approach, but unfortunately we have to deal with offsite payment what do you think?